# How to fix port for Go-Micro Service

Tags: go, go-micro

I am running go-micro , But unable to set constant port for my service. Is there any way to assign port to service.

If i am running my service, it gives different port on every execution. i want it to fix.

Comment: what are you using to create a service? Any Framework? Docker ? Share the code.

Comment: Micro Cli to create service, I am not using docker. we are in development. Only need to fix transport port for development.

Comment: while creating the docker image you acn specify the port mapping. share your docker run command

Comment: Docker is not a right way for my project development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the port in the server you must be creating for your micro-service. Since you haven't shared any sample code, here's a proposed solution that might work for you:

```
 service := micro.NewService(
    micro.Name(serviceName),
    micro.Server(
      server.NewServer(
        server.Name(serviceName),
        server.Address(":8080"),
      ),
    ),
  )

  service.Init()
```

Let me know if it is not the way you're using go-micro.

Comment: I have used Inbuild Environment variable For custom PORT. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the go micro version is not mentioned.
I have tested the above answer with go-micro version github.com/micro/go-micro/v2 v2.9.0.
But there was another issue I have faced, the go-micro server ran perfectly ok with the fixed port. However, when I have executed a gRPC client over the fixed port, the response object was returning panic.
Some working on the code and found the below fix

```
   service := micro.NewService(
      micro.Name(serviceName),
      micro.Version("1.0"),
      micro.Address(":8080"),
  )
```

With the above fix, the server was set to a fixed port and the gRPC client also responded with success.